# Insert with select, dependent on the values in the table inserting into EDITED

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

So I need to figure out how to insert into a table, from another table, with a where clause that requires me to access the table that I am inserting into. I tried an alias from the table I am inserting into, but I quickly found out that you cannot do that. Basically, what I want to check is that the values that I am inserting into the table match a particular field within the table that I am inserting into. Here is what I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO "USER"."TABLE1" AS A1
SELECT * 
FROM "USER"."TABLE2" AS A2
WHERE A2."HIERARCHYLEVEL" = 2
AND A2."PARENT" = A1."INSTANCE"
```

Obviously, this was to no avail. I've tried a couple other queries, but they didn't me anywhere, either. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I would like to add rows to this table, not add columns to the table. The two tables are of the exact same structure -- in fact, I extracted the data already in table1 from table2. What I have in table1 currently is a bunch of records who have NO PARENT, but an instance. What I want to add is all the records who have a parent in table2 that are equal to the instance in table 1.

Comment: Why don't you use a JOIN to find the rows you need?

Comment: You need to have some kind of link/join and restriction on A1 in your subquery. If the subquery doesn't work on its own (as a top-level query), fix that first.

Comment: @danielsepulvedab Please elaborate... I am not sure I understand. Are you trying to say do something like, 
SELECT * FROM
(TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.INSTANCE = TABLE2.PARENT)?

Comment: @vwegert , I think the issue that I am running into, to start, is that I cannot alias the table that I am inserting into -- as I mentioned in the OP. However, if I remove the alias and explicitly define the schema and table inside of the select statement, I get another error

Comment: @AlexisAlias I don't know the relationships between the tables, so I can't give a complete answer. First you need to write a query that return the rows you want to insert. Look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @danielsepulvedab , The two tables are exactly the same in structure. In fact, the data existing in table 1 was extracted from the table that I am attempting to extract from, again. I am not trying to join the tables and get more columns. I am now trying to add more rows to the table on the condition that the table I am extracting from has it's parent column equal to the instance column in the table that i am inserting into. For example, if I have a record in table one whose instance is x, all records from table two whose parent is x should be added to the table, as it's own row.

Comment: Again - and as @danielsepulvedab wrote as well: The subquery needs to be functional on its own, and in the form you specified above, it isn't. You can't just drop an arbitrary table into the WHERE clause and expect the DBMS to figure out what to do with it on its own.

Comment: @vwegert My solution worked precisely how I wanted it to. Moreover, the subquery is, in fact, functional on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to join on a table when inserting. The solution with the subselect where you select from the table, is the correct.

Aliasing the table you want to change is only possible with UPDATE, UPSERT and MERGE. For these operations it makes sense, as you need to match a column and then decide if you need to update it or insert something instead. In your example the line from table1 that you match is not relevant, as you don't want to change it, so from the statement point of view it is not really relevant that the table you use in your subselect is the same that the one you insert into.

As alternative, I can suggest you following solution, which is equivalent with yours:

```
INSERT INTO "user"."table1"
SELECT 
   A1."ROOT",
   A1."INSTANCE",
   A1."PARENT",
   A1."HIERARCHYLEVEL"
FROM "user"."table2" AS A1
WHERE A1."INSTANCE" in (select "PARENT" from "user"."table1")
AND A2."HIERARCHYLEVEL" = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

This gave me the answer I was looking for, although I am sure there is an easier -- or more efficient -- way to do it.

```
INSERT INTO "user"."table1" 
SELECT 
   A1."ROOT",
   A1."INSTANCE",
   A1."PARENT",
   A1."HIERARCHYLEVEL"
FROM "user"."table2" AS A1,
     "user"."table1" AS A2
WHERE A1."INSTANCE" = A2."PARENT"
AND A2."HIERARCHYLEVEL" = 2
```